# Convert xml data to csv table using Python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.8

I'm using Python 3.8 and I'm wanting to convert the below (Example xml) data from xml to a table in csv format. There are lots of examples online but I haven't found any that produce a table from xml data formatted as below. (I'm new to Python 3 and don't even know where to start).

**Example xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<observations>
-<station tz="Australia/Brisbane" description="Brisbane" forecast-district-id="QLD_PW015" lon="153.0389" lat="-27.4808" type="AWS" stn-height="8.13" stn-name="BRISBANE" bom-id="040913" wmo-id="94576">
-<period wind-src="metar_10" time-local="2021-07-11T09:30:00+10:00" time-utc="2021-07-10T23:30:00+00:00" index="0">
-<level type="surface" index="0">
<element type="apparent_temp" units="Celsius">14.0</element>
<element type="delta_t" units="Celsius">4.4</element>
<element type="gust_kmh" units="km/h">19</element>
<element type="wind_gust_spd" units="knots">10</element>
<element type="air_temperature" units="Celsius">16.6</element>
<element type="dew_point" units="Celsius">7.8</element>
<element type="pres" units="hPa">1022.0</element>
<element type="msl_pres" units="hPa">1022.0</element>
<element type="qnh_pres" units="hPa">1022.0</element>
<element type="rain_hour" units="mm">0.0</element>
<element type="rain_ten" units="mm">0.0</element>
<element type="rel-humidity" units="%">56</element>
<element type="wind_dir">WSW</element>
<element type="wind_dir_deg" units="deg">244</element>
<element type="wind_spd_kmh" units="km/h">11</element>
<element type="wind_spd" units="knots">6</element>
</level>
</period>
</station>
-<station tz="Australia/Brisbane" description="Brisbane Airport" forecast-district-id="QLD_PW015" lon="153.1292" lat="-27.3917" type="AWS" stn-height="4.51" stn-name="BRISBANE AERO" bom-id="040842" wmo-id="94578">
-<period wind-src="metar_10" time-local="2021-07-11T09:30:00+10:00" time-utc="2021-07-10T23:30:00+00:00" index="0">
-<level type="surface" index="0">
<element type="apparent_temp" units="Celsius">11.5</element>
<element type="cloud">Clear</element>
<element type="cloud_oktas">0</element>
<element type="delta_t" units="Celsius">4.1</element>
<element type="gust_kmh" units="km/h">33</element>
<element type="wind_gust_spd" units="knots">18</element>
<element type="air_temperature" units="Celsius">16.7</element>
<element type="dew_point" units="Celsius">8.7</element>
<element type="pres" units="hPa">1021.8</element>
<element type="msl_pres" units="hPa">1021.8</element>
<element type="qnh_pres" units="hPa">1021.9</element>
<element type="rain_hour" units="mm">0.0</element>
<element type="rain_ten" units="mm">0.0</element>
<element type="rel-humidity" units="%">59</element>
<element type="vis_km" units="km">10</element>
<element type="wind_dir">SW</element>
<element type="wind_dir_deg" units="deg">218</element>
<element type="wind_spd_kmh" units="km/h">26</element>
<element type="wind_spd" units="knots">14</element>
</level>
</period>
</station>
```

**Ideal Table:**

```
description          pres      dew_point    rel-humidity    wind_spd_kmh
Brisbane             1022      7.8          56              11
Brisbane Airport     1021.8    8.7          59              26
```

**Working Script**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
file = minidom.parse('.xml')
  elems = file.getElementsByTagName('station')
  for ele in elems:
    with open('.csv', mode = 'a', newline = '') as fcsv1:
      dta = csv.writer(fcsv1, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ')
      row = []
      row.append(ele.attributes["stn-name"].value)
      subelems = ele.getElementsByTagName('element')
      for subel in subelems:
        if subel.getAttribute('type') == 'air_temperature':
          row.append(subel.firstChild.nodeValue)
          for subel2 in subelems:
            if subel2.getAttribute('type') == 'pres':
              row.append(subel2.firstChild.nodeValue)
              for subel3 in subelems:
                if subel3.getAttribute('type') == 'dew_point':
                  row.append(subel3.firstChild.nodeValue)
                  for subel4 in subelems:
                    if subel4.getAttribute('type') == 'rel-humidity':
                      row.append(subel4.firstChild.nodeValue)
                      for subel5 in subelems:
                        if subel5.getAttribute('type') == 'wind_spd_kmh':
                          row.append(subel5.firstChild.nodeValue)
                          for subel6 in subelems:
                            if subel6.getAttribute('type') == 'cloud':
                              row.append(subel6.firstChild.nodeValue)
                          dta.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is a start. I did this really fast when waiting meeting to start and I am pretty sure, that **minidom is not the best way to do this**. It seems to work though on my machine, so you are welcome to try. Note that I did not do everything what you wanted, you have to finish it, because this is not the place for ready answers, when you have not put your code to the thread start.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

file = minidom.parse('something.xml')

elems = file.getElementsByTagName('station')

print('description', 'pres', sep=';', end='\n')

for ele in elems:
    print(ele.attributes['description'].value, ';', sep='', end='')
    subelems = ele.getElementsByTagName('element')
    for subel in subelems:
        # check here with if "subel" element contains correct value (pres) for type (attribute)
            # if it does, print here node value
```

output (when last two rows are written):

```
description;pres
Brisbane;1022.0
Brisbane Airport;1021.8
```

Basically same using https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html (my opinion is that this is far more better than minidom):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElemTree

root = ElemTree.parse('yourfile.xml').getroot()

print('description', 'pres', sep=';', end='\n')

for elem in root.findall("./station"):
    print(elem.attrib['description'], ';', sep='', end='')
    subelem = elem.findall("./period/level/element[@type = 'pres']")
    print(subelem[0].text)
```

Comment: Hi barbwire, Thank you. Your answer worked. If say pres is missing from the xml, how do I add a zero in place of the missing value?

Comment: You just have to check the value with if. But as I tried to say, minidom is not the best way to do this. In your answer you have so many loops inside the loop that I am confused. I added alternative way by using https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html